# Suntour Raidon 27.5+ 120mm air fork

Tags: repair, suspension

i woke up this morning to my suspension feeling really odd. It is really hard to push down and stays down until I lift my wheel off the ground. What makes it even weirder is that it is making a noise like some air leaking.

What happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to the Bicycle Stackexchange! So what was your question again? As this website is dedicated to primarily answering questions, please reformulate yours to something one can actually answer.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov I edited to include what is, I guess, the most likely question. Confirmation from Frank would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The Raidon is an air spring, oil damped fork. It sounds like an internal valve is blocked or stuck shut, and that is resisting fork compression and rebound.

Suntour does provide a range of servicing manuals and videos, but unless you are an experienced bike mechanic you should take the bike to a good local bike repair shop and have them deal with it. Suspension forks have very specific servicing procedures that must be adhered to.